# Faulty opacity coloring in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, debugging, transparency

Lately I've been having trouble with the colors in TikZ. When using opacity, the original color completely changes (red > blue-ish, yellow > green). Honestly I have no idea of the cause, but this question might help to identify it since I don't know where to look.

If I execute the code provided, my result is **(a)**, while normally it should be **(b)**, which are imported images. I'll supply them here so the code below can compile: [**fill red**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhPOK.png) and [**fill opacity**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOjVK.png).

Package versions (the ones I suppose are relevant):

```
tikz.sty    2015/08/07  v3.0.1a  (rcs-revision 1.151)
pgf.sty     2015/08/07  v3.0.1a  (rcs-revision 1.15)
xcolor.sty  2007/01/21  v2.11    LaTeX color extensions (UK)
```

and here's the code

```
\documentclass[margin=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=base, font=\bfseries] at (-1,0) {(a)};
\node[anchor=base, font=\bfseries] at (-1,-3) {(b)};

\node at (1,-2) {\includegraphics[scale=.16]{fill}}; % https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhPOK.png
\node at (4,-2) {\includegraphics[scale=.16]{fillopac}}; % https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOjVK.png

\fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\fill[red, opacity=.5] (3,0) rectangle (5,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[PDF download](http://cl.ly/0e0s2R2k2E0B)

Comment: This looks quite impossible. Could you upload the PDF file?

Comment: Latest TexLive - all ok.

Comment: Your code can not be compiled, because the images `fill` and `fillopac` are not known. The line `(a)` in your code not use green color, instead it you have red. If you like to have transparent imported images, than those images should be such.

Comment: @Symbol1 Uhhh that's interesting. When opening the .PDF *separately* (not from compile), the image is OK? :|

Comment: @Symbol1 Never mind. I still have it. It disappears if I press *spacebar* (quick preview on Mac). Where should I upload it?

Comment: @Zarko I have provided the images in the question for download.

Comment: Maybe some viewer problem

Comment: @Alenanno, I test with your images and the both lines are the same! If this matter, today I upgrade my MikTeX installation and have recent versions of all relevant packages. I check with Sumatra and Reader DC.

Comment: @Zarko I did upgrade, the result is the same. :/

Comment: I have a bit newer packages: `xcolor 2007.02.24`, `pgf 2015.09.01` and `tikz (v 3.0.1a) 2015.08.29` (hich has complete manual in comparison to your version, I guess).

Comment: @Zarko I posted those version to give more info, but I've been having this problem for a while.

Comment: I will make an answer, where I will show my test result and will erase it after your read it. I haven't any clue, what is going wrong in your place.

Comment: @Zarko You can post in chat if you want. I'm there.

Comment: @Aleano, I newer chat ... so I little bit afraid it :(. And I already send my answer. See, if in it provided information have any valuer to you.

Comment: @Zarko Chat is very friendly! You should try it. Anyway, the only difference is what you said earlier, that your Tikz is slightly more recent.

Comment: About 10 years ago i had used some bad icc profile in windows system for viewsonic display, it caused wrong colors in images. Maybe something similar in interpreting your pdf by viewer?

Comment: @Leonid I don't know, but I recently reinstalled my OS, so if there's a problem, it's probably not me.

Comment: This looks like a viewer choosing the wrong blend mode issue. What reader are you using? Put the PDF to some online place.

Comment: @percusse Mac's default viewer, Preview. Link to pdf in the question (bottom). I'm downloading Adobe Reader now to test it.

Comment: Okular and MuPDF have no problem with the PDF file.

Comment: Do you still have this problem? Can you make a new directory somewhere and a new file and copy the code into the new file. Then compile with `TEXMFHOME=/noneatall pdflatex <filename>.tex`. If you are not in the same directory, you'll need to specify the path to the file and not just the file name.

Comment: [Probably just a new file is good enough if the PDF looks OK to other people, but I'd cover everything to be sure.] By the way, the PDF is no longer there.

Comment: @cfr uhm the images are a bit too big for the question maybe. :P there's a link to them anyway in the code. The questionvlooks better without them I think. As for your comment, I can try that but tomorrow.

Comment: Just roll it back. You are probably right.

Comment: @cfr, do I un-delete my answer? In it I show, that the source of this problem is not TikZ. Beside me, many others confirm,l that this problem cannot reproduce. ON this I conclude, that the question is actually off-topic.

Comment: @zarko yet this is not the only question on a PDF reader. This still relates to TikZ in some way, even if TikZ is not the cause. I don't remember having problems with colours in other occasions besides LaTeX. I'll check better tomorrow.

Comment: @Zarko I'm not convinced it is a viewer issue. If it was, it should not make any difference whether the PDF is opened separately or by the editor on compilation. Unless the viewers are different in the two cases. It would be good to check the time stamps within the viewer application for the PDFs displayed.

Answer (score 2):

I test your code:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[margin=15pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=base, font=\bfseries] at (-1,0) {(a)};
\node[anchor=base, font=\bfseries] at (-1,-3) {(b)};

\node at (1,-2) {\includegraphics[scale=.16]{fill}};
\node at (4,-2) {\includegraphics[scale=.16]{fillopac}};

\fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\fill[red, opacity=.5] (3,0) rectangle (5,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In log file I got the following list of used files:

```
 *File List*
standalone.cls    2015/07/15 v1.2 Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2015/07/15 v1.2 Default configuration file for 'standalone' c
lass
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1 (rcs-revision 1.151)
     pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1 (rcs-revision 1.15)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1 (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1 (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
    fill.png    Graphic file (type png)
fillopac.png    Graphic file (type png)
```

And picture cut from Sumatra is:

[image]

and from Adobe DC is the same:

[image]

enter image description here

Both images I present by windows Snipping tool. I have 2 year old Dell monitors with LED back-light with low-cost no-name graphics car in PC with Windows 10 OS. The same I see an my HP laptop with Windows 8.1 OS.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but I want to try to confirm what I think is the same bug, and this is far too long for a comment. I use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     \fill[orange, opacity = 1] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
     \fill[orange, opacity = .99] (2,0) rectangle (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And I see the following screenshot:

[image]

The image on the left is correct, and has opacity=1. When I back this up just a bit to opacity=.99, I get something green.

I've tried opening this in several pdf viewers for my Mac, with varying results. The following viewers seem to reproduce the BUG:

- Preview
- Skim

And the following seem to have NO BUG:

- Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro
- QuickLook, i.e. space bar on a Mac
- Google Chrome

So this bug does seem to exist, but might not involve tikz.

I have posted the [pdf file here](http://cl.ly/030n0Z2h1n0K), and the [log file here](http://cl.ly/212a211D1u0k) in case anyone wants to take a look.

EDIT: [This post](https://discussions.apple.com/message/29105188#29105188) on an Apple support forum seems also to refer to this same bug.

Comment: I had the same issue with Preview/Skim (Skime uses the same engine provided by OSX) and suddenly it disappeared. Unfortunately I can't tell what happend ...

Comment: At the moment I _can’t_ reproduce this behavior on my System (neither in Skim nor in Preview). My versions: Preview is 8.1 (877.7), Skim is 1.4.14 (88) and OS X is 10.11.2 (15C50). My file list: http://pastebin.com/HtHyZGDH.

Comment: @Tobi, I have the same versions of Preview (877.7) and Skim (88), but my OS X version is 10.11.3. I was having this same problem before upgrading, though.

Comment: Strange … I had the issue with 10.11.2 but it somehow disappeared. The bug seems to be in OSX’ PDF engine and not in TikZ, though …