# Usage of TikZ fill opacity impacts PDF color rendering (PDF viewer dependent)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, mac, acrobat

Consider this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [fill opacity=0.5] (a) {some text in a  TikZ node with opacity};
\end{tikzpicture}

\textcolor{blue}{SOME TEXT WITH COLOR}

\clearpage

\textcolor{blue}{SOME TEXT WITH COLOR}% THIS IS OK!

\end{document}
```

I compile with pdflatex, (up-to-date TeXLive 2017 as of 2017/12/07; original document used latex+dvipdfmx), then I open the file on my Mac OS either in Skim or in Adobe Acrobat Reader. Result:

[image]

On top the Acrobat rendering, on bottom the Skim one.

Is this the same problem as [Faulty opacity coloring in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285955/faulty-opacity-coloring-in-tikz) ?

Apart from not using at all the `fill opacity` key, how do I fix this in my document, if at all possible?

This arose in a real-life document, of more than on hundred pages, and it impacts the whole document. In the MWE above however, on page 2, the situation is back to normal.

I have some delicate mwe where I can recreate the problem on page 3 via using some `\href` various `\hyperlink` macros etc... inside some description environment but it is very delicate because taking out one sentence makes the problem go away (for example removing the description environment makes the problem on that page disappear, even if replacing it by some `\begingroup...\endgroup`).

And anyway removing the `fill opacity` usage fixes that page 3 and fixes all pages in my starting point document (the documentation of `xint` package).

Adding how Acrobat 10.1.16 on my mac renders page 2, colour is then fine:

[image]

Comment: Does it work if you use `text opacity` key instead?

Comment: Adobe Reader `10.1.16` and Skim `1.4.29` on mac os x `10.9.5`.

Comment: @percusse, no, using `text opacity` changes nothing to the way Acrobat displays the document.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Windows between Acroread and SumatraPDF.

Comment: @percusse  With Acrobat the same `\textcolor{blue}{text}` renders differently on page 1 and on page 2. Thanks for testing on Windows!

Comment: @percusse, on your machine, does Acrobat use same blue on page 1 and page 2 ? and is this blue like in my post for Skim or Acrobat on page 2, or the darker sort, as if opacity was applied to it?

Comment: Skim blue on both pages with no difference. Same with SumatraPDF viewer.

Comment: @percusse ok, s/Skim/same/ ... ;-) ?

Comment: I can't reproduce in Okular on Linux, either. The blue is the same on both pages.

Comment: @cfr adding `mac` and `acrobat` tags as it seems to be acrobat (on mac) issue then, my `acrobat` says it is up to date but hasn't gotten an update for years, possibly because I am sticking with mac os x mavericks.

Comment: This is a known issue, see thread: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1055077 
If you scroll down, Adobe staff points out it is a color management problem by Apple..
You can either roll back to reader 9.5.x or use other non-Adobe software. No matter, you should file a bug report.

Comment: @Georges I have been through the whole thread, and if that issue is really the same as above, then it is a bit abysmal that Adobe says it knows a fix (even if that fix is needed due to an Apple change) but deliberately did not apply it to its Acroread 10 series but only (possibly) for Acroread 11 (I am not sure and can't test). This business of programmed obsolescence, be it Adobe, Apple or whatever is quite disgusting, and it is a rather deeply true fact that we are members of a society which replaces ethics with consumerism and pseudo-moral rigor.

Comment: @jfbu could not have said it any better. I recently had a license with adobe acrobat pro X, then they announced support will be discontinued. Updates popped up and I updated without thinking. Had to purchase a new license, so next thing is boycotting adobe altogether. Sorry, I couldn't be of further help.

Comment: @Georges you were of great help thanks for linking Adobe forum. I am thinking about whether to add something there but suspect I would need to open some account not sure I want to do that. I followed link to https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1059137 but not sure if same thing. In my mwe, the color darkening may be off on pages with only text. I guess, in design context, PDFs always have some sort of elements on the page making it show everywhere. In an ironical move, I can hope most everyone has the consumerist frenzy so my document (xint.pdf) will look fine to them `;-)`

Comment: Haha I will certainly be squinting! This thread is indeed related yet focuses on the faulty rendering (see post#47) and/or user display settings (see post#38). If one believes post#53, it seems the source is Adobe, since the user reports the same issue under windows.
Last piece of information I have, is to do the following: Under System Preferences >Displays >Color >(note the default profile then select)sRGB IEC61966-2.1 then restart adobe and check. Next, reset to default profile. Restart adobe and check. Then reselect the above mentioned colored profile. That's a shot in the dark there! ;-)

Comment: @Georges I have tried out the sRGB IEC61966-2.1 color profile which has immediately given an irreal violet tint to my mac book air screen (!) then I re-start Adobe Reader 10.1.16 and my original issue is still there ... (I tried all four proposed Color Profiles and none works; there are hidden per default, the only one shown is LCD color -- I see it in French).  Re-reading your hint I followed it exactly as said and problem still there. By the way, some advices on the adobe site point to Color Profile options I don't seem to have in my free Adobe Reader 10.1.16

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69943/discussion-between-georges-and-jfbu).